# Can the validity of time-independent perturbation theory wavefunctions decrease over time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, hilbert-space, perturbation-theory, time-evolution

In time independent perturbation theory one obtains an approximation $\psi^{(1)}$ to the actual energy eigenstates $\psi$ of the new system.

However since this approximation is not itself a stationary state in the new system, it will evolve over time. Does this mean that, in the Hilbert space, the discrepancy between the approximated eigenstate and the actual eigenstate could increase and decrease over time since the values of $\psi^{(1)}(t)$ in state space will change over time and could get closer to the actual eigenstate $\psi(t)$ which evolves only by a phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume a discrete spectrum. If the approximate eigenstate is a good approximation, it will be a superposition of the corresponding actual eigenstate with coefficient $\approx 1$ and other actual eigenstates with small coefficients. Since the other eigenstates are orthogonal, the discrepancy (as I would define it) does not change with time.

Comment: Ah so are you saying that eventhough each actual eigenstate in the superposition will evolve with a different rate of gain of a phase, the actual magnitudes of each actual eigenstate in the superposition will remain constant in time?

Comment: Yes, and even though the phases are changing, the magnitude of the difference is constant, since the other eigenstates are orthogonal.